# How to get array outside of nested array node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

i am new on node js. I have a controller function in which i am creating my own object and arrays. but i am not able to get that final array outside of final loop. Also i noticed that `console.log("3")` is not working and directly calling `console.log("4");`.

Here is the code

```
async function fetchLeague(req, res, next) {
    try {
        //get types
        let types = await Leaguetype.find({});

        let mainarray = {};
        mainarray['filters'] = [];
        console.log("1");
        types.map(async (type) => {
            console.log("2");
            let typess = {};
            typess.title = type.title;
            typess.totalCards = '5';
            typess.sections = [];
            mainarray['filters'].push(typess);
            var categories = await Leaguecategories.find({"league_type_id": type._id}) ;
            categories.map(async (category) => {
                console.log("3");
                let allcategories = {};
                allcategories.id = category._id;
                allcategories.title = category.name;
                allcategories.cards = [];
                typess.sections.push(allcategories);
                let card = await League.find({"league_category_id": category._id}) ;
                card.map(async (league) => {
                    let allleague = {};
                    allleague.card_title = league.title; 
                    allleague.pool_price = league.pool_price; 
                    allleague.entry_fee = league.entry_fee; 
                    allleague.total_spots = league.total_spots; 
                    allleague.start_time = league.start_time; 
                    allleague.end_time = league.end_time; 
                    allcategories.cards.push(allleague);


                });
            });
        });
        console.log("4");
        res.send({status: 0, statusCode:"success", message: "Successfully 1 inserted.", data:  mainarray});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('no', error);
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check `categories` value. `console.log(categories)` .. may be it returns an empty array.

Comment: @MEDZ when i `console.log(categories)` its giving me a array with all my values.

Comment: Was the number "4" logged before or after it?

Comment: Not related with the problem, but you are accessing db in a loop which is not a good idea. I advise you to get the all related data in one go.

Comment: @SuleymanSah any example do you have please. I am completely new to nodejs

Comment: @JagveerSingh we need to see your mongoose model codes, sample data, and the expected result. If you can ask a new question with these information, we can help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is this: calling .map on an array and supplying an async function returns an array of promises, not an array of transformed values.

```js
const arr = ["test1","test2","test3"]
const returned = arr.map(async (val) => val)
returned.forEach(val => console.log(val.__proto__.toString()))
```

This is also the reason, why console.log("3") is not being called, since you are not awaiting the promises. This means, node is just skipping over it and continues with your code.

This should fix your problems

```
async function fetchLeague(req, res, next) {
try {
    //get types
    let types = await Leaguetype.find({});

    let mainarray = {};
    mainarray['filters'] = [];
    console.log("1");
    Promise.all(types.map(async (type) => {
        console.log("2");
        let typess = {};
        typess.title = type.title;
        typess.totalCards = '5';
        typess.sections = [];
        mainarray['filters'].push(typess);
        var categories = await Leaguecategories.find({"league_type_id": type._id}) ;
        await categories.map(async (category) => {
            console.log("3");
            let allcategories = {};
            allcategories.id = category._id;
            allcategories.title = category.name;
            allcategories.cards = [];
            typess.sections.push(allcategories);
            let card = await League.find({"league_category_id": category._id}) ;
            card.map(league => {
                let allleague = {};
                allleague.card_title = league.title; 
                allleague.pool_price = league.pool_price; 
                allleague.entry_fee = league.entry_fee; 
                allleague.total_spots = league.total_spots; 
                allleague.start_time = league.start_time; 
                allleague.end_time = league.end_time; 
                allcategories.cards.push(allleague);


            });
        });
    })).then(() => {
         console.log("4");
         res.send({status: 0, statusCode:"success", message: "Successfully 1 inserted.", data:  mainarray});
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log('no', error);
    return []
}}
```

Comment: still console giving me this `1
 2
 2
 2
 2
 4
 POST /api/league 200 82.341 ms - 293
 3
 3
 3` result.

Comment: Could you please clarify? From which line is this getting printed, are all console.logs being triggered?

Comment: all console are getting printed but not in sequence. As you can see that `1, 2 and 4` are getting printed but `3` is printing in last.

Comment: Yes! it works but now i think problem with inner loop `card.map(league => {`. this gives result in first array only.